# Acessar banco pelo MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

Não consigo acessar uma base de dados pelo MySQl Workbench. Aparece a seguinte mensagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, pelo PHPMYADMIN, eu consigo.
Como faço para conseguir acessar pelo MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Está fazendo a conexão sobre uma maquina remota? Se sim, seu usuário deve ter permissão para se conectar. O phpmyadmin utiliza um usuário localhost para conexão, se está utilizando o mesmo usuário de uma maquina remota o mysql ira bloquear o acesso. Vai precisar rodar um GRANT ALL no mysql  e gerar permissão sobre o usuário para permitir o acesso de sua maquina remota.

Comment: Sim, o banco está em outra maquina. Como dou permissão para o usuário que no caso é `root` acessar, através do workbench?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para dar permissão ao usúario para acesso você pode rodar essa querie:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* TO'username'@'seu_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

TROQUE:

**db_name** pelo nome de seu banco de dados.

**username** pelo seu usúario no banco de dados.

**password** pela sua senha de acesso.

**seu_ip**   o ip da maquina que irá acessar o servidor mysql.

Após esse comando execute:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

para atualizar os privilégios sobre o usúario.

Observações:

> Alguns provedores de hospedagem não permitem conexão remota ao mysql.

Também pode:

> Utilizar ao invés de seu ip o coringa **%**, mas isto permitirá conexões ao mysql com esse usuário sobre qualquer interface de rede, e por segurança não é aconselhável.